# How to publish the application to multiple webapp created in azure from visual studio 2017

Tags: azure, web-applications, deployment, visual-studio-2017, azure-web-app-service

I have one ERP application developed in visual studio 2017 and it is hosted in azure web apps .I am creating separate web apps for each client now its around 40 webapps and increasing the count. I am using "vs 2017 publish"  to publish one by one for each updates, but it was time consuming. Spending approximate 3 hrs to publish same application to each clients. I need a solution for publish to all these clients in single publish, means when I click on publish button in 2017 , need to update to all these 40 web apps in same time. Kindly help me to find one proper solution for this.

Thank you

Dominic

Comment: All of them in the single solution? It seems that it's hard to achieve that.

Comment: @JoeyCai Thank you for the reply.Yes. single solution and only one project. i need to deploy that to all clients after bug fixing or adding new features. Unfortunately now i am publishing one by one and it is time consuming job. So that need to publish to all web apps in single publish

Comment: @user3614949 You need an automated build/release pipeline. VSTS has saved us so much time and frustration.

Comment: @JasonP Thank you for the comment. i am new in VSTS. is it possible to set all web apps details while publishing?

Comment: @user3614949 Yes, you can do just about anything with the available build/release tasks, including deploying to many apps with separate settings.